# Issue while debugging angular2 rc project using VS code and chrome debugger extention

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code, rc

I am facing issues while debugging using VS code editor.But I am able to debug using chrome developer tools.

Break points are not hitting and its showing in grey circle.

Also in console I am getting this error .

[image]

Here is my launch.json.

```
"version": "0.2.0", 
"configurations": [
{
"name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
"type": "chrome",
"request": "launch",
"url": "http://localhost:3000/",
"sourceMaps": true,
"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
"userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome",

        // Uncomment this to get diagnostic logs in the console
     "diagnosticLogging": true

/"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
"webpack:///c:/Users/anisha.rn/angular-2-hello-world/": "${workspaceRoot}/"
}/

    },
```

THis is my app folder structure.
[Folder Structure][2][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWo1o.png

This is my index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular 2 Hello World</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```